# Libraries of Python in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3, libraries

I downloaded anaconda and there are pre-installed libraries. How can I use all those in Sublime Text 3 ? I have a mac os, can I set path to that python with all libraries or what should I do ?

Comment: How do you want to use it ?

Comment: for machine learning, libraries such as tensorflow, numpy and matplotlib

Comment: You can learn more about build systems in sublime text. Basically, just add python path with your modules installed and you can run your scripts with `Ctrl+B`